# OpenCV Assertion Error mat.hpp line 570

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

When i try to implement this code to call all the color to be use later.. it shows an error.. Does anyone know what is wrong with this code.. tq

```
// Extracting pure colors to use in demo
    const int ncolors = 16;
    std::vector<Scalar> colors;
    for (int n = 0; n < ncolors; ++n) {
        Mat color(Size(1, 1), CV_32FC3);
        color.at<float>(0) = (360) / ncolors * n;
        color.at<float>(1) = 1.0;
        color.at<float>(2) = 0.7;
        cvtColor(color, color, CV_HSV2BGR);
        color = color * 255;
        colors.push_back(Scalar(color.at<float>(0), color.at<float>(1), color.at<float>(2)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix `color` is a 1x1 matrix with 3 channels, so you should access as:

```
color.at<Vec3f>(0)[0] = 360.f / ncolors * n;
color.at<Vec3f>(0)[1] = 1.f;
color.at<Vec3f>(0)[2] = 0.7f;
```

You should access it similarly when you construct the Scalar.